Ubuntu 24.04.1 - lost access to Google Drive and Network Drive after update
I've updated my Ubuntu laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad E470) to 24.04.1 LTS from 22.10 (after waiting for the prompt in my updater to appear) and have noticed that I've no longer have access to Google Drive, nor can I connect to a network drive on my home network. I've outlined the issues below
Google:

In "Settings" and "Online Accounts", I've entered my Google Account credentials. All other Google services (Mail/Contacts/Calendar) have connected fine and I can see them in the various Ubuntu system apps (eg Contacts shows my Google contacts, Calendar my Google calendar) but I no longer see any Google Drive folder in the file browser, nor does the option to mount the drive appear in the dock.

Network:

I have a network drive (WDMyCloud) which, on 22.10, I was able to connect to easily from the file browser with no issues and which worked flawlessly with no further interaction needed on my part.
Since the update, this drive has now disappeared (like Google Drive above, the option to mount it in the dock has also gone) and it no longer seems to be picked up automatically when I try going to "Other Locations", nor does it recognise the ip address of the drive when I enter it into the "Enter Server Address" box - any attempt to enter a protocol (eg smb://) results in the box turning red.
Interestingly, I am able to successfully ping the ip address from the terminal and the address is recognised with no packet loss.

Has anyone else had these issues since updating to 24.04.1?
Any ideas on how to get these back?

I had the same issue, I removed the account from Ubuntu Settings -> Online Accounts and re-added it by ticking both entries per service I wanted to add. I then only selected the services in the ubuntu menu that I had enabled. It then worked.
Just updating the authentication of the existing entry didn't work.
I hope this helps.

Thanks for the suggestion - I've tried doing this a couple of times, each time with a reboot straight afterwards but the Google Drive folder is still not appearing, nor is the option there to mount it.

@HimOverThere do the Google permissions match the services you tickets in the Ubuntu online accounts? I think my issue was a mismatch.
For example, if you didn't allow Gnome to edit your calendar but did tick the "calendar" box in the gnome sync settings

I've double checked all permissions and have made sure that Ubuntu basically has access rights to do everything possible, but still no joy whatsoever.

Just encountered this today.  I upgraded to 24.04 and I have tried deleting and re adding my google account, and the drive shows up in the sidebar in nautilus/files, but I get a permission denied even though I seemed to be logged in properly via my browser.
Edit... there are a bunch of tick boxes in the browser confirmation page... I had to check them all and this was not terribly obvious.  Solved.  it works now.

Can you clarify the list of tickboxes you checked? I'm sure I'm checking them all but maybe I'm missing one.
(although I'm not even getting the drive appearing in the sidebar in my file browser...)
